# Is it necessary to get a masters degree for industry jobs in Machine Learning or AI?

Tags: masters, computer-science, career-path

I’m about to enter my ultimate year of a physics BSc at a top university in the UK, and have done a computational physics  internship with a research group at the university and am currently doing an internship at Harvard that requires strong machine learning skills. I was hoping this would be enough qualification to justify being able to get an entry level job in ML or AI and use that to one day lead myself into a job working with DeepMind, OpenAI, IBM Watson - places like these. I also have some fantasies about working in game design randomly, although I think that needs less a graduate degree and more a portfolio of coded games perhaps.

However, with those ML and AI jobs I was citing, does it behoove me to get a graduate degree if I want to one day get hired by them? I personally am quite drained from exam stresses and don’t think academia suits me as much as I used to think it does, but if it’s necessary for my goals in industry it might be worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, I think, on what sort of job you want. For people in the trenches, even at IBM/Watson, an undergraduate degree is probably enough to get hired. You would likely be a team member building things at the direction of a manager. Creativity would be in the "how to do this" rather than in the "what do we need to build" area.

However, at the level of doing research at IBM, and I assume others, the requirements look a lot like they would for an academic position. Lots of the people there have doctorates, actually. I don't know that a PhD is necessary to get hired, but the more education you have, the better your chances.

I know people at both these sorts of levels at IBM and at Oracle.

It used to be that at IBM the trench types could get a doctorate paid for at the company, but that option has disappeared for a while now. They might be a bit flexible about giving you some time-slack to do it, depending on the manager, but funding is unlikely.

At smaller companies and especially at startups it is probably much more flexible, but also risky. I also know people doing interesting things at such small software shops who have a more basic formal education though they are good at learning on their own and staying at the forefront.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking in the wrong forum - the place to find the answers to these questions are with the employers themselves.

To work at DeepMind [see their website](https://deepmind.com/careers/what-expect-application-process/). They don't have formal degree requirements but they will perform an aptitude test. As long as you know how to do your stuff, you're fine.

To work at OpenAI, again [see their website](https://openai.com/jobs/#lever-f5c8d70e-c8a2-4696-82e1-635d106e649c). Like DeepMind they don't have formal degree requirements but they do require [published papers](https://jobs.lever.co/openai/588c1d80-4632-4d5c-a535-9f2c8c80c501) or [2+ years of ML experience](https://jobs.lever.co/openai/a0d3b158-14a0-48db-b38c-1c94bb18f69b).

And the same goes for [IBM](https://www.ibm.com/employment/technicaltalent/) and whatever employer you're interested in.

Good luck.